# Infopath 2013 Extracting Fileupload Attachments through the Client Object Model CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, csom

I have an infopath form published to a sharepoint subsite. All the records are stored there. I can add attachments through file upload control but How do I access both their file names and the data from an external application through the client object model. I can access the xml but i don't see the attachments. I also saw that there is supposed to be a folder called attachments with the an listitem id and the attachments but I don't see that either. I am able to download and open the attachments from the sharepoint webpage infopath form so I know there are there. I am in sharepoint 2013 and infopath 2013 office 365. Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0):

Attachments are stored within InfoPath XML files as Base64 encoded strings.  You can access them programatically by parsing the XML, decoding the Base64 string, and then using information from Microsoft's site to determine the file's size, name, and contents. Microsoft provides an example on [their site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892730) using C#, but you can do this using any language you want.  Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks so much,  that helped a great deal and I implemented a solution against my office 365 site.   The one issue I do have is that when I have 3 or 4 attachments and update them I sometimes get a message too large error. I guess the web service does support that sometimes when the attachments are big and the xml is over 2 megs.   Any idea if there is a way to set the 365 site to allow bigger transfers ......

Comment: Glad to help. I don't have any experience with SharePoint Online, as I use SharePoint in an Enterprise setting. You should be able to configure this setting in the Admin console from what I find using some basic searches.